# How to query data from one collection based on the data from another collection in cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in cloud firestore.
1. Users - It contains the user_id and an array of user_ids of friends.
2. Posts - It contains the post_data and user_id of the user who posted the data.

I want a user to see only those posts which are posted by their friends.

I am making a social media kind of app in Flutter using Firebase Cloud firestore as database.

I can only think of one way:
Make a local list of user_ids of friends of the user. Then fetch the post and check the user_id in the post and check it against the local list. If it contains that ID, show the post to the user.

Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore does not have any "join" type queries that can apply across multiple collections.  You will have to make at least one query for each collection whose data you want to consider.  An alternative is to duplicate data across collections so that one collection has all the required information in order to  satisfy the query.